# Is there any point using try {some code} finally {empty block}?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
try
{
    //some code that might throw exception
}
finally
{

}
```

I came across above code in a project, and I can't understand what is the use of such a try-catch-finally block.

Note: no `catch` block, and empty `finally` block.

Comment: No. No need to use try also. try needs catch or finally .

Comment: `I can't understand what is the use of such a try-catch-finally block.` The main use is confusion.